# UITableView with grey lines on the side when trying to add a background. How do you get rid of these lines?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

[You can see the lines on the side of the table http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7098/screenshot20100808at543.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7098/screenshot20100808at543.png)

How do you get rid of these lines on the side of the table?

Comment: Please host your images using the Stackoverflow built-in uploader. Other websites, as you can see, end up deleting the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the lines.
The problem is in the labels' background color.
Just set the background color (.backgroundColor property) of the label (the one that contains the text "Item 1", "Item 2" etc.) to `[UIColor clearColor]` inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.